# Проблема с отображением графика. C++

Tags: visual-c++

Так, ну тут такая проблемка, что программа выдаёт график, но он сразу пропадает. Я просто уже попробовал system("pause") поставить куда угодно. Может я что-то делаю не так. Подскажите пожалуйста. Закоментированные строчки это как я пытался решить проблему, можете не обращать внимания на них.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define graphic(x) (x*x-2*x+4) //график который будет строится

int main()
{
//while (1) {
float x;
HDC hDC = GetDC(GetConsoleWindow());
HPEN Pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255, 255, 255));
SelectObject(hDC, Pen);
MoveToEx(hDC, 0, 85, NULL);
LineTo(hDC, 200, 85);
MoveToEx(hDC, 100, 0, NULL);
LineTo(hDC, 100, 170);
for (x = -8.0f; x <= 8.0f; x += 0.01f) // O(100,85) - center
{
MoveToEx(hDC, 10 * x + 100, -10 * graphic(x) + 85, NULL);//10 - scale
LineTo(hDC, 10 * x + 100, -10 * graphic(x) + 85);
//if (x >= 7.0f || x<=8.0f) system("pause");
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
}
```

Ps: сори, если что-то не так указал на форуме и т.д, в первый раз просто пользуюсь)

Comment: Попробуйте в окне командной строки и без всяких `pause` - график у меня никуда не пропадал.

Comment: Вы можете перед `return 0` написать `getchar()` у меня ничего не проподает

Comment: Спасибо, реально надо было просто getchar() указать